# Point inside triangle explanation 

Tags: php, algorithm, math, geometry

I found only algorithms and implementations for "hit test" in triangle, like this: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/06/18/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-triangle-with-mathematics-no-hit-test-involved/, and this: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html

But in the project I work I've found this code:

```
public static function pointInTriangle($x, $y, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3)
{   
    return self::side($x, $y, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3) &&
           self::side($x, $y, $x1, $y1, $x3, $y3, $x2, $y2) &&
           self::side($x, $y, $x3, $y3, $x2, $y2, $x1, $y1);
}

private static function side($x, $y, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3)
{
    if ($x1 - $x2 != 0) {
        $k    = ($y1 - $y2) / ($x1 - $x2);
        $s1   = $y3 - $y1 - $k * ($x3 - $x1);
        $s2   = $y - $y1 - $k * ($x - $x1);
    }
    else {
        $s1   = $x3 - $x1;
        $s2   = $x - $x1;
    }
    return ($s1 * $s2) >= 0;
}
```

Can you explain to me how this works? Why do we need to calculate $k (which is slope between x1, y1 and x2, y2 points, isn't it?)?

I have problems to understand first clause. Why do we need to subtract, for example, y1 from y3 and multiple k to subtraction result of x3 and x1? What will do this operation? And what is  $k * ($x3 - $x1)? $k is slope between points $x1,$y1 and $x2,$y2, not between $x1,$y1 and $x3,$y3.

I have some knowledge of algebraic geometry. In other words, if main formula (equation of straight line) is y = kx + b, we have 0 = y - y1 - (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1) for points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and then f(x3, y3) = y3 - y1 - (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x3 - x1)?

Am I right?

Comment: `$k * ($x3 - $x1)` is how much the line rises, going from `$x1` to `$x3`. There's no way to understand this without learning the basics of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Your first equation (`0=...`) describes the line; I can't make much sense of the second ("f"?).

Comment: I know this doesn't help analyze the current code, but the side() function shouldn't need to test if `$x1 - $x2 != 0`.  It is not hard to do this operation without divisions; and the exact equality test is a red flag for numerical instability.

Comment: Beta, how to deriver a formula for $s1 and $s2? Please describe it in your answer. f(x3, y3) = 0 in my second formula, because f(x3, y3) = y3 = y1 + k * (x3 - x1), and then i push y3 to other side of equation within swapping 'plus' to 'minus' and 'minus' to 'plus'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `side` answers the question "Are the points **x** and **x<sub>3</sub>** on the same side of the line formed by the points **x<sub>1</sub>** and **x<sub>2</sub>**". If the answer is "yes" for all three choices of **x<sub>3</sub>**, then the point **x** is inside the triangle.

The implementation of `side` is kind of clumsy. Look at the first clause:

```
if ($x1 - $x2 != 0) {
    $k    = ($y1 - $y2) / ($x1 - $x2);
    $s1   = $y3 - $y1 - $k * ($x3 - $x1);
    $s2   = $y - $y1 - $k * ($x - $x1);
}
```

Yes, `$k` is the slope of the line from **x<sub>1</sub>** to **x<sub>2</sub>**; `$s1` and `$s2` are the altitudes of the points **x<sub>3</sub>** and **x** above this line, respectively.

Look at the second clause:

```
else {
    $s1   = $x3 - $x1;
    $s2   = $x - $x1;
}
```

Here, `$s1` and `$s2` have a different meaning. They're how far the two points are to the right of the vertical line.

Either way, this:

```
return ($s1 * $s2) >= 0;
```

gives the correct answer. (You'll get into trouble with a line that is almost vertical-- there is a cleaner, safer way, if you're comfortable with vector algebra).

**EDIT:**

Let's rewrite a line from the first clause:

$s1 = $y3 - $y1 - $k * ($x3 - $x1);
$s1 = $y3 - $k * ($x3 - $x1) - $y1;
$s1 = $y3 - **($k * ($x3 - $x1) + $y1)**;

The part in bold is the y-coordinate of the point on the line directly below (or above) the point **x<sub>3</sub>**. So `$s1` is the height of **x<sub>3</sub>** above (or below) that point.

Comment: Execuse me... I re-read your answer after a lot of time - and I don't know which formula do you use to call $s1 altitude to line (x1,y1-x2,y2) from (x3,y3) point. Can you show this formula?

Comment: @GuyFawkes:  `$s1 = $y3 - $y1 - $k * ($x3 - $x1);`

Comment: :) i asked about common formula name. In all line and altitude equations I seen slope is not using in this way.

Comment: I think it's not real altitude of triangle. It can't be calculated in this way.

Comment: I uderstood. $s1 is not altitude, it's just DISTANCE in Y-coordinates between point (x3,y3) and point on line above or below it with SAME x coordinate. So, if we have
y = y1 + slope * (x - x1), where y is Y-coordinate of point below or above (x3, y3), we can to get Y distance as y3 - y = y3 - y1 - slope * (x - x1), because x === x3, we can rewrite it as y3 - y1 - slope * (x3 - x1).
Am I right?

Comment: @GuyFawkes: You seem to be using "altitude" in a sense I do not know. But you seem to understand the algebra.

Comment: Altitiude in triangle is perpendicularly to its side, but line from point to side may has any angle.